# ou was not a ResultSet - MS SQL Driver issue with 6.x version and Hibernate

Tags: java, sql-server, jdbc

I'm using Hibernate 5.0.10, Java 7 and Microsoft JDBC Driver 4.1 for SQL Server version 4.1.8112.100.

After changing to Microsoft SQL Server JDBC driver 6.4, I'm getting this error:

> Current CallableStatement ou was not a ResultSet, but getResultList was called

It fails on the last line on getResultSet

```
public List<DocListResultExt> getDocuments(DocList doc) {
    StoredProcedureQuery query = entityManagerFactory
            .createEntityManager()
            .createNamedStoredProcedureQuery("getDocList");

    query.setParameter(....);

    List<Sp_get_doc_list> spList = (List<Sp_get_doc_list>)query.getResultList();
```

Any idea why it suddenly seems not compatible with the current code?

Comment: What is the code of this stored procedure, specifically, does it contain `SET NOCOUNT ON` or not?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Thanks @Mark Rotteveel seem adding `SET NOCOUNT ON`resolved the issue. Kind of doesn't explain why the driver would handle this differently, but that's ok.

Comment: To be honest, I would expect the same problem to occur with earlier driver versions, but it is the only thing I could think of that would explain the problem.